# python does not run for loop

Tags: python, subprocess

I am working on a project which will extract all the ssids and passwords from a windows system
(Note:I am not using this script for malicious pourposes.I just want to apply my subprocess module skills)
But in this program,The for loop I wrote is not executed by python can anyone please help me with this? tnx.

```
import subprocess , sys , re
a = subprocess.check_output(['netsh' ,  'wlan' ,  'show' ,  'profiles'])
a = a.decode('utf-8')
a = a.replace('    All User Profile     :' , '')
a = a.replace('User profiles' , '')
a = a.replace('<None>' , '')
a = a.replace( 'Profiles on interface Wi-Fi:', '')
a = a.replace(':' , '')
a = a.replace('Group policy profiles (read only)' , '')
a = a.replace('---------------------------------' , '')
a = a.replace('-------------' , '')
print(a)
a = a.replace('  ' , '')
f = open('ssids.txt' , 'w')
f.write(a)
f.close()
f = open('ssids.txt' , 'r')
d = f.read()
l1 = []
print(str(f.read()))
for line in f.read():
    l = subprocess.run('netsh wlan show profiles "' + f.readline(line) + '"' , capture_output = True , text = True)
    print(l)
f.close()
print('follwed')
print(str(l1))
```

Comment: You already called `f.read()` in the previous `print()` statement, which consumed all of the data in the file.  So when you called `f.read()` again, there was nothing left to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `f.read()` several times and print its contents. Use `with open` to open and close it safely.

```
import subprocess
a = subprocess.check_output(['netsh' ,  'wlan' ,  'show' ,  'profiles'])
a = a.decode('utf-8')
a = a.replace('    All User Profile     :' , '')
a = a.replace('User profiles' , '')
a = a.replace('<None>' , '')
a = a.replace( 'Profiles on interface Wi-Fi:', '')
a = a.replace(':' , '')
a = a.replace('Group policy profiles (read only)' , '')
a = a.replace('---------------------------------' , '')
a = a.replace('-------------' , '')
print(a)
a = a.replace('  ' , '')

with open('ssids.txt' , 'w') as f:
    f.write(a)

with open('ssids.txt' , 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l = subprocess.run('netsh wlan show profiles "' + line + '"' , capture_output = True , text = True)
        print(l)
print('follwed')
```